# Laravel vue-router config for frontend, exclude backend

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vue-router

I using laravel + vuejs
Backend use laravel (/admin)

In `routes/web.php`

```
...
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.\,-]*');
```

When I run some url
test.com/admin
test.com/admin/users
-> All redirect to welcome layout

How to config to vue-router only run exclude /admin (backend)

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '^(?!admin).+');
```

It's just a regex problem, try this

Comment: Hi @Cemal, How exclude both /admin and /api?

Comment: @HaiTruongIT
Like that => '^(?!admin)(?!api).+' 
Put answer in solved ;)